# JQuery calc width for child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this

```
<ul class="example">
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something 2</li>
    <li>Something 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want a jquery code to calculate the width for the **li** based on number of them. I tried to use this code but it's not working :(

```
$('.example > li').css('width', 100%/$('.example').length());
```

Any solution?

Comment: try:
`$('.example > li').css('width', Math.floor(100/$('.example').length())+'%');`

Comment: not working man :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` is not a function. It is a property. [Read More](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

And you must count `length` of `li` items and not the `ul` wrapping it.

So, I did just two changes to your code:

1. modified `length()` to `length`
2. modified selector `$('.example')` to `$('.example li')`

```js
$('.example > li').css('width', 100/$('.example li').length + '%');
console.log($('.example li').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="example">
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something 2</li>
    <li>Something 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's working, but you should add '%' like this
`$('.example > li').css('width', 100/$('.example li').length + '%');`

Comment: Modified the answer as per your requirement. By default it takes px. I have changed it to accept % values.

Answer (score 2):

You did everything correctly, you just did not use `length` as a property.

```js
var elements = $('ul#ul > li');
var len      = elements.length;
var width    = (100 / len) + "%";

elements.css('width', width);
```

```css
li {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="ul">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>as</li>
    <li>dsk</li>
</ul>
```